# How to use Python as a back end for Ruby on Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie to python.
Basically I am working on a college project and using Ruby on Rails for front end and Python for backend.
But could not figure out how to use python through Ruby on Rails.

As in how to run console based commands of Python through Ruby on Rails.
I have been searching since long but could not find anything substantial.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think a better question is why use Python in the backend instead of Ruby?

Comment: You are probably better off using Django. The Rails front end isn't exactly its strong point, which is why people often use node.js or angular.js as the front end to a Rails API.